# Unique strong on page load to validate future requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, next.js

I have the page and when a user clicks on a link then a send a request to this api endpoint:

```
fetch(`${getRootUrl()}/api/page/page-id/incrementViews`);
```

Where page-id changes depending on the page.

However someone could simply copy and run that url multiple times in their browser to fake views.

What options do I have to validate this to ensure only the current request/page loaded can do it?
Specifically in react/nextJs.

Comment: Is the requesting page open to the public or do your users have to authenticate?

Comment: The page is open to the public

Comment: It depends on how sophisticated you want to get with this. The bottom line is no matter what you do to check the authenticity of the request on the server side (headers, clickIds, etc.), it can all be faked by using something as simple as CURL. But one basic way to do this is to assign a unique ID to each visitor and store it in a cookie (or local storage) and then send that ID with each request in the header. That way your server know it's coming from a visitor. But then again, one can easily get that ID and then use it to fake requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can set local storage and can make check before api call with this local storage value. It can be something like you set local storage value as true in the first render then you can set it as false after first visit in this url.